# How to make a absolute positioned div attatched to a relative div keeping the z-index?

Tags: reactjs

[image]

Here you see, The search filter dropdown is positioned absolute and the parent child does not have relative for now. Now when the screen is scrolled the filter dropdown is still in previous position, as expected from absolute positioning. When I give parent relative position the drop down zindex is gone and the filter dropdown contains inside the parent. Due to this only half of dropdown is visible.
so my question is how to make it look like this while it should be attatched to the input field

A simple code on how it looks is

```
<div class='accordian-bottom' style='width: 100%;...'>
    <div style='position: relative'>
        //input
        <div class='dropdown' style='position: absolute;..'>
            //dropdown code
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post a minimum reproduceable code so that we can help you debug it. We don't have any idea what your code looks like. All answers you will get would be just a guess instead of a concrete fix.